# simulate Y if Y = log(X) and X ~ Gamma in R

Tags: r, distribution, simulate, gamma

This question is very closely related to posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/density-of-y-logx-for-gamma-distributed-x) and also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/how-to-quickly-sample-x-if-expx-gamma).

Let's say that random variable X = Gamma(k, theta), and I am interested in simulating Y, where Y = log(X).

Could you suggest R-package which allows to do it (or suggest an R-code)? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to extract `Y` samples, just try:

```
#set the number of samples
n<-10000
Y<-log(rgamma(n,k,theta))
```

Then, for instance, you can `hist(Y)` to see the distribution.

Comment: Thank you! But then I would like to ask a related question -- can we say that density of Y is simply log (dgamma(n, k, theta) ) ?

Comment: No, you cannot. The first link you provided answers to this question.

Comment: Exactly, thank you again, and would like to ask the last (naive) question that may help to solve (find examples in R) this question when using different distributions. When X ~ Gamma and Y = exp(X), then Y follows log-Gamma distribution. How do we call distribution when Y = log(X), i.e. what is a general name?